# How to install Ros Groovy Beta 2

Tags: ros, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm trying to do a fresh install of Groovy Beta 2 on Ubuntu 12.10, like documented on the wiki.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop
```

The problem is that now there is no package ros-groovy-desktop as it was in Beta 1.
Is there any new package to install it, or do I have to install all packages manually?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50453/how-to-install-ros-groovy-beta-2/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably an error, I created a ticket:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/276

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1